# Segfault when using memmove()

Tags: arrays, c, chararray

I am working on a program written in C that recursively walks a given directory in order to print out the Nth largest files and their sizes in bytes. I am using two arrays to account for the filesystem entry names and filesystem entry sizes respectively.

EDIT: I have updated my program to implement the suggestions shared in the comment section. My focus now is on correctly implementing a swap operation within my `iSort` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>

// number of files to display size information for
const int N = 10;

// a struct used to hold filesystem entry names and corresponding sizes in bytes
struct info {
    char name[1024];
    int size;
};

/* A simple implementation of insertion sort that will operate upon
   an array of info structs, sorting them by their member size in
   ascending order */
void iSort(struct info *fs_info[], int size, int info_size)
{
    int i, j, key;

    for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        key = fs_info[i]->size;
        j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 0 && fs_info[j]->size > key)
        {
            printf("info_size: %d\n", info_size);

            // TODO complete a swap operation
            memmove(fs_info[j + 1], fs_info[j], info_size);

            j = j - 1;
        }
        fs_info[j + 1]->size = key;
    }
}

void get_size(char *path, struct info fs_info[N], int info_size)
{
    static int items_added = 0;
    static int max_size = 0;

    struct stat st;
    if (stat(path, &st) == 0)
    {
        if (items_added < N) // if array capacity will not be exceeded
        {
            strcpy(fs_info[items_added].name, path);
            fs_info[items_added].size = st.st_size;

            if (st.st_size > max_size)
                max_size = st.st_size;

            items_added++;
        }
        else
        {
            // do a comparison to determine where to insert
            // sort first
            iSort(&fs_info, 10, info_size);  // this function call results in a seqfault
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error getting stat for entry %s: %d\n", path, stat(path, &st));
    }
}

void walk(const char *currDir, struct info fs_info[N], int info_size)
{
    DIR *dir = opendir(currDir);
    struct dirent *entry;

    if (dir == NULL)
    {
        // directory could not be opened
        return;
    }

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
        {
            // if directory is current dir or parent dir
            continue;
        }

        char path_to_entry[1024];
        snprintf(path_to_entry, sizeof(path_to_entry), "%s/%s", currDir, entry->d_name);

        // use path_to_entry to call stats on the entry
        get_size(path_to_entry, fs_info, info_size);

        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR)
        {
            // recursively visit subdirectories
            walk(path_to_entry, fs_info, info_size);
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <target directory>\n", argv[0]);
    }

    const char *target_dir = argv[1];

    struct info fs_entries[N];
    const int info_size = sizeof(struct info);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        strcpy(fs_entries[i].name, "");
        fs_entries[i].size = 0;
    }

    printf("Finding %d largest files in: %s\n", N, target_dir);

    walk(target_dir, fs_entries, info_size);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%s : %d\n", fs_entries[i].name, fs_entries[i].size);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Currently, the `memmove()` invocation in `iSot()` results in a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error, I am working on improving this function now. Any suggestions in the interim are appreciated. Thanks also to those who commented on this question earlier.

Comment: Don't use two arrays, use one array of structs.

Comment: It doesn't actually make a difference, but why do you put `[N]` in the parameter declarations of `entries`, but not `sizes`?

Comment: You need to make a copy of the `path` string when putting it into `entries[items_added]`. The memory of a variable created in a loop becomes invalid when the next iteration of the loop occurs.

Comment: Insertion sort requires you to swap the two array elements in the inner loop, not just assign one to the other.

Comment: @Barmar thank you. I was using `[N]`in the declaration of `entries` to see if this would change anything, no strong reason to do so.  Do you know what difference it makes for the compiler to provide size information or not?

Comment: As I said, it doesn't make any difference in this case. The size information isn't used for the first array dimension.

Comment: re: `isort()`... Go experiment with `memmove()` shifting multiple contiguous elements within the boundaries of a fixed size array... Get comfortable with `memmove()` and you'll save lots of 'hacky' looping code (that is all-to-often wrong.) Experiment with a separate program until you've got the understanding...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: Please give us a program not a bunch of snippets that we have to assemble.

Comment: [qsort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) is your friend.

Comment: Since your program targets POSIX systems, you might as well use the `nftw` function to walk the filesystem rather than roll your own. Also, `d_type` is only on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not so much an ***answer*** as it is an example of how one might code this with a bit less *fiddling about* with every bit/byte.

I don't run a flavour of UNIX, so this offering is untested and may contain typos and even bugs. I hope not.

```
#include <stdio.h>  // From 'generic' to 'specific'
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>

const int N = 10;

// Global array holding names and sizes
struct {
    char name[ MAX_PATH ];
    size_t size;
} biggies[ N ], wrk; // and a working buffer.

/* "Global" is bad for large projects.
 * In this 'utility' program, global saves a LOT of typing/reading.
 * Seek clarity, not conformity,
 *
 * "wrk" is used to buffer ALL paths encountered.
 * Notice that each recursion is an EXTENSION of its parent.
 * ONE working buffer to deal with.
 */
void walk() {
    size_t len = strlen( wrk.name ); // The path so far...

    DIR *dir;
    if( ( dir = opendir( wrk.name ) ) == NULL )
        return;

    wrk.name[ len++ ] = '/'; // append a slash ahead of strcpy() below

    struct dirent *entry;
    while( ( entry = readdir( dir ) ) != NULL ) {
        if( strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0 )
            continue;

        // Notice how each 'local' name is written to "the right spot" in one buffer
        strcpy( wrk.name + len, entry->d_name );

        if( entry->d_type == DT_DIR ) // directory, so recursion...
            walk();
        else {
            struct stat st;
            if( stat( wrk.name, &st ) != 0 ) {
                fprintf( stderr, "Error stat'ing '%s'\n", wrk.name );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }
            // Add this info to working buffer.
            wrk.size = st.st_size;

            // Find where to 'insert' this (if it is larger than descending ordered list
            for( int i = 0; i < N && biggies[i].size > wrk.size; i++ ) {} // loop

            if( i < N ) {
                // Slide smaller ones down (don't go out of bounds)
                memmove( biggies[i + 1], biggies[i], (N-i-1) * sizeof biggies[0] );
                // Copy this one in place.
                memcpy( biggies[i], &wrk, sizeof biggies[0] );
            }
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[])  {
    char *target_dir = argv[1]; // This is okay, so far...

    if( argc != 2 ) {
        printf( "Usage: %s <target directory>\n", argv[0] );
        puts( "Using current directory..." );
        target_dir = ".";
    }

    strcpy( wrk.name, target_dir );

    printf( "Finding %d largest files in: %s\n", N, wrk.name );

    walk();

    for( size_t i = 0; i < N && biggies[i].size != 0; i++ )
        printf( "%s : %d\n", biggies[i].name, biggies[i].size);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good use of `strcpy( wrk.name + len, entry->d_name );` to reduce string copying.  On normal return, could use `wrk.name[ --len] = 0;` to restore `wrk.name[]`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Right-o, but, for this use (in recursion), it doesn't really matter what's "the rest" of the buffer. Whatever it was, it'll be clobbered almost immediately... `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass the address of `fs_info` to `iSort()` function. `fs_info` is a pointer to first element of `fs_entries` array, which is enough to sort the array if the size of array is known. Also, you don't need to pass the size of element of array to `iSort()`.

`iSort()` function implementation:

```
void iSort(struct info *fs_info, int size) {
    for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        int key = fs_info[i].size;
        struct info x = fs_info[i];
        int j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 0 && fs_info[j].size > key) {
            fs_info[j + 1] = fs_info[j];
            j--;
        }

        fs_info[j + 1] = x;
    }
}
```

Use `memmove()` in `iSort()`:

```
void iSort (struct info *fs_info, int size) {
    for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        int key = fs_info[i].size;
        struct info x = fs_info[i];
        int j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 0 && fs_info[j].size > key) {
            j--;
        }

        if (j != i - 1) {
            memmove (&fs_info[j + 2], &fs_info[j + 1], sizeof(*fs_info) * (i - j - 1));
        }

        memmove (&fs_info[j + 1], &x, sizeof(*fs_info));
    }
}
```

Call `iSort()` function like this:

```
iSort(fs_info, N);
```

There is a lot of scope of improvement in your code, like, it would be good to have array of pointers to `struct info` instead of array of `struct info`, so that, during sort simply swapping the pointers required instead of swapping whole structure. Leaving it up to you to identify the improvements and implement them.